# flood mitigation

Tags: flood

I would like to carry out flood mitigation using non-structural measures like wetland restoration, detention ponds and infiltration ditches or ponds. How can GIS help me in siting and visualizing the effects of my measures when they are in place?

Comment: I just searched on https://www.google.com/search?q=flood+mitigation+gis and got lots of hits.  Would you be able to edit your question to include the results of your research so far, please?

Comment: Also, you had a tag for the ArcGIS platform but is that what you are using, and a constraint on the solutions you are seeking?  If so, which particular product(s) from the ArcGIS platform are you using or have available to use to try and do this?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [Leapfrog Hydro](http://www.leapfrog3d.com/products/leapfrog-hydro)